# Dynamic webpages: store images in a seperate table/database?

Tags: php, database, image, url, path

I just started to use dynamic instead of static webpages so I store everything in my database now. The thing is that I don't really know what's the best way to save my images within the database.

I decided to store the image file paths instead of the images itself in a database. But should I save the urls (up to 50 images per article so that means 50 possible urls) in the same table or should I create another one just for these images?
What's the best way to do this?

**Related question:**
Do I need a seperate column for each image? In other words, do I have to create 50 columns for each possible image per news article?

Comment: Create another table that holds a page id/reference and an image path. There may be many entries per page, not 50 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create another table with two columns not 50. You can have several rows per page.

```
pageref | imagepath
--------+------------
home    | image01.jpg
home    | image02.jpg
home    | image24.jpg
home    | image65.jpg
about   | image03.jpg
about   | image04.jpg
```

I say two columns, you might want to store the order in which they appear, the datetime they were uploaded, their dimensions etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna give it a try.